# Calling dynamic SQL or stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm using a search object query (found on the internet, wish I could give credit to the developer) to search database for the columns needed when I write queries. The output search object query allows me to enter the type of table to look in (partial name) as well as the column name (partial name) I'm trying to find. I've been attempting to modify the search object query so it returns the 1st value (Top 1) it finds. This would help me to easily see at a glance if the column has the particular type of data I'm looking for.

I've attempted to write it both as a stored procedure that I could pass two parameters (partial table and partial column name) and I've also tried using dynamic SQL (my first attempt at using it, so I'm a novice when it comes to use it). I had moderate success with the use of dynamic SQL, but can only get it to produce one result rather than be called multiple times for all the results in my search object output. The code I used is shown here:

```
--  This is the search object query found on internet
Use masterdb

Select a.name, b.name
From sysobjects a
Inner Join syscolumns b On a.id = b.id
Where b.name like '%Result%'
  And a.name like '%Lab%'
Order By a.name, b.name

--  This is a separate query I used to test calling the data with dynamic SQL
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(100), @tablename VARCHAR(100)

SET @value = 'Result'
SET @tablename = 'LabSpecimen'

DECLARE @sqlText NVARCHAR(1000); 
SET @sqlText = N'SELECT Top 1 ' + @value + ' FROM testndb.dbo.' +     @tablename

EXEC (@sqlText)
```

If I use the search object query and search for tables that have lab and column names that have result, I might get output like this:

```
LabMain,ResultID
LabSpecimen,ResultCategory
LabSpecimen,ResultDate
LabSpecimen,Results
```

I would like to have the search object query pull data from the table in the first column and the column name in the 2nd column and return the first value it finds to give me a sample output for the given column name/table. Output would look like this:

```
LabMain,ResultID,E201812310001
LabSpecimen,ResultCategory,ExampleCategory
LabSpecimen,ResultDate,20181231
LabSpecimen,Results,34.20
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried formatting the code by adding the spaces but did something wrong.

Comment: Would you prefer to just have the column type there? Would that be enough?

Comment: This is very open to injection, You need to be quoting your object names properly using `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: I went ahead and posted a separate answer (I kinda hate how the previous answerer wouldn't simply add a blurb about SQL Injection - what it is, why your question had a vulnerability, and why his answer didn't)  Oh well.  Hope my answer helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I *really* didn't want to have to post an answer to this, but here goes.

**So, the first, really-really-huge thing is: SQL Injection.**  SQL Injection is the #1 security vulnerability for something like a dozen years running, per OWASP.  Basically, SQL Injection is where you use dynamic SQL that has any fragment of the sql command being populated by a user.  So in the OP's case, this section here:

> ```
> SET @value = 'Result'
> SET @tablename = 'LabSpecimen'
>
> DECLARE @sqlText NVARCHAR(1000); 
> SET @sqlText = N'SELECT Top 1 ' + @value + ' FROM testndb.dbo.' +     @tablename
>
> EXEC (@sqlText)
> ```

... if the end incarnation would be that @tableName and @value are populated by the user as part of their search?  Then the user can do a 'search' that ends up injecting sql statements that the server runs directly; for a cheap example, imagine this for @value:

> ```
> 3' ; drop table @tableName --
> ```

... which would go ahead and drop every table that matches the @tablename you passed in.

Anyway, so, as we go through this problem, we're going to keep SQL Injection in mind at every step.

**Problem #1: How to get the tables/columns that match.**

You pretty much already nailed this.  The only thing missing is to put it into a temp table so that you can loop through it (and limit it down to U-types, since otherwise you'll get stored procs and system tables.)  I went ahead and had it also hit the Schema information - that way, if you have tables in different schemas, it'll still be able to get the results.

```
declare @tableNameFragment varchar(100) -- note: these top 4 lines will eventually
declare @columnNameFragment varchar(100) -- be changed to stored proc args

set @tableNameFragment = 'Performance' -- and populated by the user calling
set @columnNameFragment = 'status' -- the proc (instead of hard-coded.)

declare @entityMatches TABLE (TableName varchar(200), ColName varchar(128))

insert into @entityMatches
Select sch.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + sysobj.name as TableName, syscol.name as ColName
From sysobjects sysobj
Join syscolumns syscol On sysobj.id = syscol.id
Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES sch on sch.TABLE_NAME = sysobj.name 
where sysobj.xtype = 'U'
and (sysobj.name like '%' + isnull(@tableNameFragment,'') + '%')
and (syscol.name like '%' + isnull(@columnNameFragment,'') + '%')
```

Now, notice that while @tableNameFragment and @columnNameFragment are *used*, they're not used in a *dynamic* query.  It doesn't matter if the user puts in something malicious into those values

**Problem #2 - How to loop through your table**

Basically, you're going to need a cursor.  I hate cursors, but sometimes (like this one), they're necessary.

**Problem #3 - How to actually do a dynamic query and get a result back**

This is actually trickier than it looks.  You can't do a raw EXEC() for a return value, nor can you simply have the cmd you're executing populating a variable - because EXEC (and SP_ExecuteSql operate in a different context, so they can't populate variables outside in your script.)

You need to use SP_ExecuteSQL, but specify a return variable getting populated by the interior sql command.  For example:

```
declare @sqlCmd nvarchar(max)
declare @dynamicReturn varchar(max)

set @sqlCmd = 'select @retVal=1'

EXEC Sp_executesql @sqlCmd,
    N'@retVal varchar(max) output',
    @dynamicReturn output

select @dynamicReturn
```

**Problem #4 - How to write your Dynamic command**

Here's where things get dicey, since it's where we're using a dynamic SQL command.  The important thing here is: *you cannot use anything the user provided as an input*.  Which means, you can't use the variables @tableNameFragment or @columnNameFragment.  You *can* use the values in the @entityMatches table, though.  Why?  Because the user didn't populate them.  They got populated by the data in the sys tables - it doesn't matter if the user puts something nefarious in the input variables, that @entityMatches data simply holds the existing table/column names that match.

Also important: When you're working on code that *could* be a problem if a future dev down the line tweaks or copies/pastes - you should put comment warnings to illuminate the issue.

**So, putting it all together?  You'll have something that looks like this:**

```
declare @tableNameFragment varchar(100) -- note: these top 4 lines will eventually
declare @columnNameFragment varchar(100) -- be changed to stored proc args

set @tableNameFragment = 'Performance' -- and populated by the user calling
set @columnNameFragment = 'status' -- the proc (instead of hard-coded.)

declare @entityMatches TABLE (TableName varchar(200), ColName varchar(128))

insert into @entityMatches
Select sch.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + sysobj.name as TableName, syscol.name as ColName
From sysobjects sysobj
Join syscolumns syscol On sysobj.id = syscol.id
Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES sch on sch.TABLE_NAME = sysobj.name 
where sysobj.xtype = 'U'
and (sysobj.name like '%' + isnull(@tableNameFragment,'') + '%')
and (syscol.name like '%' + isnull(@columnNameFragment,'') + '%')

declare @returnResults TABLE (TableName varchar(200), ColName varchar(128), FirstValue varchar(max))

declare Cur Cursor For select TableName,ColName from @entityMatches
declare @cursorTable varchar(200), @cursorColumn varchar(128)
open Cur
fetch Next from cur into @cursorTable,@cursorColumn
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin 
    -- Note: the variables @cursorTable, @cursorColumn are NOT user populated
    -- but instead are populated from the Sys tables.  Because of this,
    -- this dynamic sql below is not SQL-Injection vulnerable (the entries
    -- are not populated from user entry of any sort.)
    -- Be very careful modifying the lines below to make sure you don't
    -- introduce a vulnerability.
    declare @sqlCmd nvarchar(max)
    declare @dynamicReturn varchar(max)
    set @sqlCmd = 'select top 1 @retVal=[' + @cursorColumn + '] from ' + @cursorTable
    EXEC Sp_executesql @sqlCmd,
        N'@retVal varchar(max) output',
        @dynamicReturn output

    insert into @returnResults values (@cursorTable, @cursorColumn, @dynamicReturn)

    fetch Next from cur into @cursorTable,@cursorColumn
End
close cur
deallocate cur

select * from @returnResults
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin, I have learned a great deal. Appreciate it.

Comment: @IatricSB - you're more than welcome  :-)  If this is useful, feel free to upvote and/or accept it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Create a stored procedure like below mention stored procedure.

Get the table and column name from `sysobject` & `syscolumn` and add it in hash table on the base of parameter of stored procedure. After that declare a cursor and in loop of cursor create a dynamic query of column and table name and get first row of current column from table of cursor loop. After that execute the query and update the result in the hash table. At the end of lookup select the Record from hash table. Check the below stored procedure. I hope that its helpful for you.

```
Create procedure Sp_GetSampleData
    @TName varchar(200) = ''
as
    Select  
        a.name TableName, b.name ColumnName,
        CAST('' as varchar(max)) as SampleValue 
    into 
        #Tbl
    from 
        sysobjects a
    inner join 
        syscolumns b on a.id = b.id
    where 
        (@TName='' or a.name = @TName)
    order ny 
        a.name, b.name

    declare @TableName varchar(200), @ColumnName varchar(200),
            @sqlText nvarchar(max), @Val varchar(max)

    declare Cur Cursor For
        select TableName, ColumnName 
        from #Tbl

    open Cur
    fetch Next from cur into @TableName,@ColumnName
    while @@FETCH_STATUS =0
    begin 
            set @sqlText=''
            set @Val=''
             SET @sqlText = N'SELECT Top 1 @Val=[' + @ColumnName + '] FROM testndb.dbo.' +     @TableName

            EXEC Sp_executesql
              @sqlText,
              N'@Val varchar(max) output',
              @Val output

             print @sqlText
          update #Tbl set SampleValue=@Val where TableName=@TableName and ColumnName =@ColumnName

      fetch Next from cur into @TableName,@ColumnName
    End
    close cur
    deallocate cur
  select * from #Tbl
```

Comment: copy overall the store procedure and create it in db and after that execute that store procedure like exec Sp_GetSampleData 'LabSpecimen' or exec 
 Sp_GetSampleData

Comment: Don't add comments, [edit] your answer instead. It would also be helpful to explain the code so  that people can learn from your answer instead of just copying and pasting some code from the web. See [answer].

Comment: I'm going to be a real hard-case and give this a -1, simply because you had an OP saying they were new to Dynamic SQL with an example that had an SQL Injection Vulnerability... yet you didn't say *anything* about that aspect of the situation.  Honestly, the OP would be ten billion times better off if they didn't have the answer to the question but learned about SQL Injection Vulnerability, than if they copy/pasted this answer and didn't have a clue how close to a security hole they were.   SQL Injection is the #1 most common vulnerability per OWASP.

Comment: Kevin,  Thank you for the information regarding SQL Injection Vulnerability.  The article I googled mentioned that it allowed attacks on web pages and/or web applications.  If this is a query that I keep on a laptop for personal use that is only used when searching for where a field is and what table it is in, would that be a safe use of code like this?  I wouldn't think it would be available to anyone unless they somehow hacked my computer or something.

Comment: @latricSB - that's not really a good thought process to follow.  You want to get into good development patterns, especially if you're new to an area of development.  And, well, sometimes code gets copy/pasted from one project to another ("Wait, boss, you want me to do a table column-name search?  I've got some code at home that already does that!  I can grab some of its code and reuse it")  Don't get me wrong - Liaqat's *doesn't* have an SQL vulnerability, but it's not immediately obvious why it doesn't.  Which is why a paragraph in the answer on this is needed.

Comment: Sir i made it myself. Why do you think that this is a copy/Past?

Comment: @LiaqatKundi Nobody said you copy/pasted it.  Every comment talking about copy/pasting is talking about people copy/pasting *from* this answer.

Comment: @Kevin Sir then why did I get voting in negative?

Comment: @LiaqatKundi ... did you read my first comment on this answer?  I keep checking back here to change the downvote to an upvote if you append some info about SQL Injection vulnerabilities and why your code sample isn't vulnerable.

Comment: @Kevin Yes sir you are right but I have provided a solution same as he has wanted.